# Probability of dice thrown

Tags: probability, dice

> What is the probability of getting
>
> -atleast 1 six when 6 dice are rolled?
>   - atleast 2 six when 12 dice are rolled?
>   - atleast 3 six when 18 dice are rolled?

"At least 1 six" is $1-(5/6)^6$. How can I do the next 2?

Can you please help me with some hints? I just don't get this.

Comment: @MTurgeon: How do you know? Did you assign this exercise?

Comment: [link](http://example.com)In the book, its atleast one 6.

Comment: @dfeuer One of the earlier edits wasn't referring to "at least"

Comment: [link](http://example.com) @Turgeon, so will it stay the same for atleast or will there be a change from the present

Answer (score 0):

At least two 6 when 12 dice are rolled is

1 - (probability that no 6 was rolled + probability that one 6 was rolled).

Using this, can you do the last one?

**Edit**: The probability of no 6 is $(5/6)^{12}$ (there are 12 dice). The probability of (exactly) one 6 is $12\times(1/6)\times(5/6)^{11}$: you have one die which is fixed at 6, all the other ones can be anything but 6, and you have 12 choices for which die has 6.

Comment: [link]Thanks@Turgeon, Is it prob atleast one 6 or one 6, so will it become 1-[(5/6)^6+(1/6)^6]?? ANd the last, I just cant get it

Comment: @Jaswanth Your solution is not correct; I added the probabilities. Try to understand this one computation, and if you have questions please ask. But doing the last problem should be very similar.

Comment: The edit is not correct for the chance of exactly one.  You have 12 choices which die is the 6, so the chance should be multiplied by 12.

Comment: @RossMillikan Right, thanks.

Comment: [link](http://example.com) So for the last one, it will be like the present answer-(no 6 was rolled+one six was rolled) ??

Comment: [link](http://example.com)  So, for second one the prob f no 6 is (5/6)^12 or 1-[(5/6)^12]

Answer (score 0):

The chance of no sixes in 12 dice, extending your result is $\left( \frac 56 \right)^{12}$.  The chance of exactly one six is $12 \cdot \frac 16 \cdot \left( \frac 56 \right)^{11}$, where the $12$ is the number of ways to choose which die will be the $6$, the $\frac 16$ is the chance it is a $6$, the the $\frac 56$ is the chance that all the rest are non-$6$'s

Comment: [link]but its two 6 right, so atleast 2 6 when 12 dice are rolled,

Comment: I thought so, too.  If you have the probabilities of zero and one, subtract from $1$ to get the probability of at least two.

Comment: [link](http://example.com)@ Ross Is chance of no 6 is (5/6)^12 or 1-[(5/6)^12]

Comment: Yes, a typo.  Fixed.  Thanks.